# Why do we have both __atomic_store_n and __atomic_store

Tags: c, gcc, linux-kernel

I am working on a simple linux driver and I am trying to understand how the atomic built-ins for the gcc compiler work and how they optimize performance. My question is: why do we need both `__atomic_store` and `__atomic_store_n`? What is their difference?

Comment: I doubt those atomic built-ins are used anywhere in the Linux kernel code, but it does use its own atomic functions.

Comment: I guess they don't appear in the kernel code but I need to use them in an LKM driver.

Comment: How do you know the code they generate is compatible with the Linux kernel execution environment?

Comment: Both the kernel and the hardware running it are customized, so I am aware of the underlying architecture.

Answer (score 1):

look at gcc manual for the difference between the two atomic_store functions

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html

Built-in Function: void __atomic_store_n (type *ptr, type val, int memorder)

```
This built-in function implements an atomic store operation. It writes val into *ptr.

The valid memory order variants are __ATOMIC_RELAXED, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST, and __ATOMIC_RELEASE.
```

Built-in Function: void __atomic_store (type *ptr, type *val, int memorder)

```
This is the generic version of an atomic store. It stores the value of *val into *ptr.
```

the __atomic.._n methods can be used for any integer scalar or pointer with a size of 1, 2, 4, or 8 bytes, instead the generic version is applicable to any data type.

Comment: While it's good to refer to the documentation, adding some more beyond just pasting it would be better. At least explicitly noting the different in the `val` argument being a pointer in one of the two cases.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I have read the gcc manual but don't quite understand what the word generic entails. The only difference I see is that the val variable in one case is a pointer. Does that mean that only __atomic_store works with pointers (and only pointers) as a val argument? Can the val argument in __atomic_store_n be a type int* for example?

Comment: @GaluxTrabakoulas The GCC documentation says "The ‘`__atomic`’ builtins can be used with any integral scalar or pointer type that is 1, 2, 4, or 8 bytes in length." Pointers in Linux are 4 or 8 bytes in length (depending on the architecture), so they should work for pointers too.

Comment: Ok, so I can use pointers with `__atomic_store` but can I use non pointer types with `__atomic_store_n` as well? And even if I can what is the point in having 2 functions for the same thing when one does the job for all types? Does the one have a more optimized performance for pointers than the other?

Comment: @GaluxTrabakoulas They might map to instructions with different addressing modes.

Comment: @GaluxTrabakoulas the __atomic.._n methods can be used for any integer scalar or pointer with a size of 1, 2, 4, or 8 bytes, instead the generic version is applicable to any data type.

Comment: @IanAbbott sorry if this seems a bit of a dumm question but some of these concepts are fairly new to me, could you please elaborate or give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: @Mariano by any data type you mean like structs?

Comment: @GaluxTrabakoulas I mean the `_n` variants might use instructions with "immediate" operands if `val` is a constant.